# ACF of IMA(1,1) in R

Tags: r, arima

I generate the IMA(1,1) process in R to see ACF for different values of Theta. The graphs show that ACF is always positive for both positive and negative values of Theta, is it correct or I'm wrong somewhere?

```
theta <- 0.9
d <- ts(matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=100))
e <- ts(rnorm(100,0,1))
d[1] <- e[1]
for(i in 2:100)
  d[i] <- d[i-1]-theta*(e[i-1]+e[i])
acf(d,10)
```

Theta=0.9
[image]
Theta=-0.9
[image]

Comment: That's correct; it's the "I" in "IMA" that makes it so.

Answer (score 2):

**PS:** After the comment I'm feeling in doubt of what I've done. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**UPD:** I think this part `d[i] <- d[i-1] - theta*(e[i-1] + e[i])` should be this `d[i] <- d[i-1] - theta*e[i-1] + e[i]` cause in **ARMA** only previous random parts: $\varepsilon_{i}$ - is multiplied by $\theta$'s.

**UPD:** With the help of **jbowman** I've checked the idea of positive **ACF** with more correct modeling.

---

**R** does have the functions to model the general `ARIMA` process and much more:

```
imap.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(order=c(0,1,1), ma=0.9), n=100) # modeling with positive theta
iman.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(order=c(0,1,1), ma=0.9), n=100) # modeling with negative theta
ts.plot(imap.sim) # plotting
ts.plot(iman.sim)
imap.acf <- acf(imap.sim, type="correlation", plot=T)
iman.acf <- acf(iman.sim, type="correlation", plot=T)
```

And the results:

- With positive theta:
  [image]
- With negative theta:
  [image]

Comment: I believe the correct syntax for the arima simulation is `iman.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(order=c(0,1,1), ma=-0.9), n=100)`.  I think the `d=1` is ignored, and you're actually generating an MA(1) process; the first order autocorrelation of roughly (+/-) 0.5 would support this hypothesis.  I agree, however, that `arima.sim` is the way to go.